# Run Azure Cloud KUDU with admin rights

Tags: azure, kudu, azure-cli

I am trying to do silent installation on Azure cloud using KUDU.
But the installer exe needs administrative rights, which KUDU don't have.

How can I run KUDU with admin rights?

Thanks All

Comment: What are you trying to install?

Comment: Hi I am trying to install a 3rd party application EDIdEv.
I have exe for it for silent installation

Comment: The Ashok gave the right answer